# Differential Backup of A Table In Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, sql-server-2016, restore

I will transfer the datas of a two different table to a database in reporting server Daily but i don't want to do it manually and also don't want to transfer all the datas to that databases everyday. Instead of doing it, i wonder that if i can take full backup and then day by day differential bakcup or not? Is there a way doing this logic in sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Transactional Replication

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-replicating-data-between-continuously-connected-servers?view=sql-server-ver15

It allows keep up-to-date copies of your tables at reporting server, without copying any other tables/data that you do not need

Comment: Is there any bad side of transactianol replication model? Like causing high CPU usage, disk I/O issue or RAM usage issue? What are the bad sides of it?

Comment: Bad sides - I would say its not so easy to configure, and not always easy to maintain. If you change tables that are being replicated - for example change columns - that could break replication and you will have to reconfigure